# Notifying two separate classes of property change using Mvvm Community Toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, mvvm-toolkit

My goal is essentially to have two separate classes, a searchbox and textfield, react to one another once their counterparts' values change.

I've been experimenting with the new [MVVM toolkit of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/), and I've explored the `[ObservableProperty]` command and `[RelayCommand]` annotations. However, one issue I am having is their documentation, which needs more details. This is why I am trying this place, to see if someone could shed some light on my implementation.

We have `Searchbox.cs` that happens to be an `ObservableObject`, and its automagical function `OnTextChange` automatically triggers once its value changes. That's good.

```
// Searchbox.cs

    public partial class Searchbox : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string text;

        partial void OnTextChanged(string value)
        {

            // notify Textfield about change
            //
            // Textfield.onChange(doSomething => {
            //      OnSearchboxTextChange();
            // });
            //

            Console.WriteLine("Something changed for Text!");
        }
    }
```

However, somewhere else in my app, totally separate from Searchbox is `Textfield.cs` and I also want it to react to `OnTextChange`. I made a function for it `OnSearchboxTextChange`. Now, my first implementation was just exposing Textfield and calling OnSearchboxTextChange via `[RelayCommand]` in the `Textfield.cs` class, but I thought that was not an elegant solution, since I'm exposing textfield right away.

```
// Textfield.cs

    public class Textfield
    {
        public void OnSearchboxTextChange()
        {
            // react to Searchbox value changing
        }
    }
```

I tried looking at the annotation `[NotifyPropertyChangeRecipients]` but the document is definitely unclear on its implementation. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for a messenger. The CommunityToolkit already contains one that you can use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger